# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project <project-name>:

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, exec-maven-plugin

When I build a jar file using maven build and try running it from command line. I am getting this error.

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <className>
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
        at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project <project-name>:An exception occured while executing the Java class. <class-name>
```

Tried everything I saw in Stack Overflow and Github but the problem is not resolved

Comment: Probably your `pom.xml` has an execution of `exec-maven-plugin` which is configured with a wrong class. But how would we really know, you don't post your `pom.xml`.

Comment: The class I added was correct. I cross verified it many times.
I got it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working...

Had to add the classes folder(from the target folder) in the folder where I pasted the .jar file.

Comment: files in `project/target/` are the files post compilation, if you are having an error in building these files will never be created, so how would you add/copy them in another path? where u decided to add "this .jar" that you pasted, in root path like `project/` or `project/src/main/resources` shouldn't make any diff